# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bsh/EvalError

Tags: java, android, appium

I have configured my system and trying to run my appium code and getting below error. So please help

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bsh/EvalError
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:99)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_0$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_0.java:26)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_0$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_0.java:59)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:561)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:156)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:110)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1235)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1222)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1074)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:999)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.EvalError
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add jar file bsh-1.3.0.jar . The version is up to you and project

Comment: Thanks and what does this jar do?

Comment: I dont know what does it. But the error is clear. bsh jar is missing.